# Кавычки в названии улицы: (улица газеты "Звезда")

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Есть улица, названная в честь газеты "Звезда".

Как нужно писать название?

*Улица Газеты "Звезда"­­* (к чему склоняюсь я - так как не нашла правила, по которому кавычки теряются; кроме того, в одной из местных краеведческих книг нашла такое написание) 
или 
*улица Газеты Звезда* (как пишут все СМИ, что, конечно, не эталон). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Улица Газеты «Звезда», улица Газеты «Искра» - **реально существующие названия.** Родовое слово "Газеты" пишется с прописной буквы, так как является первым словом названия, далее следует несклоняемое имя собственное в кавычках, которое **не должно искажаться.**

Comment: А вопрос-то был о кавычках. Остальное к делу не относится.

Comment: Остальное к делу относится, это полное обоснование правильности написания. Важно не только просмотреть существующие варианты, как это делается обычно, но и понять, как делается нужный выбор. Это, конечно,  более сложная задача, но и нужная, несомненно.

Comment: ВОПРОС: Нужны кавычки? ОТВЕТ 1: Кавычки нужны, дается объяснение, почему нужны. Это очень плохой ответ, очень отрицательный, никому не нужный и банальный. ОТВЕТ 2. СМИ почему-то тоже без кавычек. Но вики и тут "Звезды" закавычивает.Но главный вывод: не надо на СМИ ориентироваться.    и т.д. Это, по мнению автора,  очень хороший ответ, очень правильный, только где же ответ-то, один ПОТОК СОЗНАНИЯ. .

Answer (score 1):

Названия улиц пишутся без кавычек. 
 Вот рекомендация из справочника.

> Проспекты, улицы, площади, переулки, тупики, мосты и т. п.

В этих названиях все слова, кроме родовых **(аллея, бульвар, линия, набережная, переулок, площадь, проезд, просек, проспект, спуск, тупик, улица, шоссе**), рекомендуется писать с прописной буквы по общему правилу написания географических названий, например:
**Комсомольский проспект**, проспект **Мира;** улица **Бутырский Вал**, улица **Каретный Ряд,** улица **Кузнецкий Мост,** улица Лихоборские Бугры, Пушкинская улица, улица Народного Ополчения, улица Серпуховской Заставы, улица Сивцев Вражек, улица Теплый Стан, улица Тюфелева Роща, Елисейские Поля (улица в Париже); площадь Крестьянской Заставы, Никитские Ворота, площадь Революции; Большой Козихинский переулок, Кривоколенный переулок; Сытинский тупик; Большой Каменный мост, мост Вздохов; Ростовская набережная; шоссе Энтузиастов.

> См.: Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию. Издание четвертое, исправленное.- М.: "ЧеРо", 2001
>   Мильчин А.Э., Чельцова Л.К. Справочник издателя и автора. Редакционно-издательское оформление издания. 2-е издание, исправленное и дополненное. М.: ОЛМА-Пресс, 2003.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. Здесь кавычки не в топониме, а в названии газеты, входящей в топоним.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что Вы правы, по крайней мере с точки зрения правописания. Вики подтверждает.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B_%C2%AB%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%C2%BB_%28%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8C%29

Но тут есть один очень неприятный для "правоверных" лингвистов факт. Имена собственные, топонимы в том числе, надо писать так и только, как записано в документах. Если решение о переименовании или присвоении названия было принято с нарушением общих правил правописания, с этим приходится мириться.

И еще один момент. Топонимы на картах обычно пишут без кавычек. Правда это гарантировано касается лишь внешних кавычек, типа "*клх.* Красный Лапоть" - название колхоза без кавычек. Вполне возможно, что это правило обобщается на кавычки внутренние. Это может объяснить, почему СМИ используют такой вариант, даже если он противоречит официальному.

С первым приходится считаться, второе можно проигнорировать - и писать так, как как это в документах. Я думаю, при желании Вам не составит труда разобраться в истории названия улицы и найти текст документа о переименовании.
(+)
кстати, в Минске есть проспект газеты "Звезда", и в интернет-СМИ почему-то тоже без кавычек. Но вики и тут "Звезда" закавычивает.
(++)
Еще есть несколько улиц "Газеты Правда". Ну тут вообще полный разнобой... 
И "газеты Правда" и "Газеты Правды", но кавычки опускают все, кроме "Вики".
(+++)
В Киеве была улица Крейсера "Аврора", переименовали. В Харькове все ещё существует (другие города не смотрел). В обоих случаях на карте обозначены с кавычками, в СМИ в основном - без. Это уже начинает напоминать дурной анекдот...
Но главный вывод: не надо на СМИ ориентироваться.

Comment: Большое спасибо за аргументацию и аналогичные примеры в других городах. Действительно, наверное, стоит поискать в архиве дело о переименовании улицы; интересно, что статьи на сайте местного архива дают написание только улица Газеты "Звезда".

Comment: Ага, я нашел этот сайт, но он очень медленный, не стал вас на него посылать. )))